# I can no longer update anything using the AppCenter

Tags: appcenter

For the last month or so I have been unable to use the AppCenter to update anything. Checking for updates displays the "Getting download sizes ..."  spinning wheel as before, but once it's done, NOTHING is displayed in the window that used to list all the available updates and give me an option to update them. It's just blank save for the proforma message "Checking for updates ..." (which it's clearly not doing). Please advise! Or I'll be forced to give up on Elementary completely because if the AppCenter isn't working, Elementary isn't working.

No questions like this have been posted on this formum since 2021, so I think this is a new problem (for me only?). Here's the output of "uname -a" so you know what system version I'm using:

Linux Z990-R-AAS9U1-e6fde4c9 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I just ran it again from the command line with debugging enabled, i.e. "G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all io.elementary.appcenter", and it came right up with a list of apps to update (including the system) just like it used to. But IMHO it should NOT be necessary to do it that way (if that is what did it ...).